# Moving cakePHP installation to a different host error

Tags: php, cakephp

I moved cakephp installation to a different host and got this error(the code segment is the output I get including the php code, it is suggesting  AppController would extend AppController):

```
Missing Method in AppController

Error: The action index is not defined in controller AppController

Error: Create AppController::index() in file: app/Controller/AppController.php.

<?php
class AppController extends AppController {


public function index() {

}

}
```

My database is now located on a different host altogether and I tested the remote connection and cake doesn't complain about that anymore. Any suggestions what could've caused this?

Comment: class AppController extends Controller {
} check it down

Comment: That's what's bugging me. That is the error message output, cake tells me to create AppController that extends AppController.

Comment: yes, you should know you made a mistake : as when we use app controller we extends it with Controller . ITs a basic inheritance .Link :http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-AppController.html

Comment: The AppController in the AppController.php extends Controller, what you see above is the error message I get when I load host.com/app. I am familiar with what inheritance is.